# JavaScript Error Element is null: while interacting ShadownDom element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am writing code in Javascript to automate the website https://www.fashionette.co.uk/. I have to use cookies when the user lands on the page for the first time

I am writing the following code to get cookies:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webdriver;
WebElement element= (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector(\"[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']\");");
            element.click()
```

it locate element in browser correctly:

[image]

But In Intellij it gives me error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "element" is null
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with those excessive ' s?

Comment: Actually I simply want to accept cookies by clicking "Accept All" button.

Comment: my point is you should probably clean up your code

Comment: I would really appreciate your help/ suggestions.

Comment: you'll have to escape the right 's

Comment: not at all. You still have way too much ' s, and you're not escaping any. do you know what it means to escape a character in a String?

Comment: Do you mean escaping like this?  WebElement element= (WebElement) js.executeScript(" document.querySelector(\'#usercentrics-root\').shadowRoot.querySelector(\"[data-testid=\'uc-accept-all-button\']\")");

Comment: with this above statement error is gone but now it cannot locate element:      "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "element" is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Java` create a browser instance and find elements:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");           
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");   
WebElement WE = driver.findElementByCss("YourCSSSelector"); 
WE.click();
```

If you are using `JavaScript` change your into:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) js.executeScript
("document.getElementById('usercentrics-root').
shadowRoot.querySelector(\"[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button'])\");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this javascript code and syntay issue has been resolved but it gives error element is null now.  "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "element" is null